# Devops Pipeline task to access multiple subscriptions

Tags: azure, azure-devops

A Devops pipeline is linked to one subscription. Is it possible to access resources in multiple subscription from one task in a pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to access resources in multiple subscription from one task in a pipeline?

AFAIK, I do not think it is possible to access resources in multiple subscription from **one** task.

Just ask you know, we could only link one subscription in one task:

[image]

If deployed to multiple environments, we could create a Release pipeline with multiple environments. Then add Deploy task for every environment and choose different Azure Service Connections in different environment. Then you could deploy one app to different Azure environment through one release pipeline.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable with light house configurations.

https://adatum.no/azure/multi-subscription-deployment-with-devops-and-azure-lighthouse

You would have to create a new azure devops SPN. You can then in turn give this SPN account via light house access to the subscription.